# What are our options for safeguarding a minor asking about potentially dangerous activities?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

I saw [a post on Travel Stack Exchange by a minor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/140841/can-i-travel-from-germany-to-england-alone-as-an-unaccompanied-minor/) and tried to respond as best I could, but I'm concerned it *may* be something beyond the remit of the Q&A format here.

If any admins could take a look and consider whatever safeguarding policies (or similar) are in place, I'd sleep easier.

If that's not possible, what are our options/responsibilities in these situations, across Stack Exchange?

Comment: Welcome to Meta, @MrHGV... it's an unforgiving place sometimes. FWIW I think you have a valid concern here, but this post may be getting downvoted because it's not really our remit to deal with it. I'm going to re-tag your post as a "support" question rather than a discussion, as that may help SE staff see it. You'll also want to consider [contacting Stack Exchange staff directly](/contact) about this, but there may unfortunately be little they can do without falling into the traps laid by privacy laws.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the Stack Exchange network. It seems to be only realated to Travel.SE, so why not ask it on [Meta.Travel.SE](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/questions)?

Comment: @ArtOfCode - thank you.

Comment: @SebastianSimon - because, as stated, I'm new here?  And I'm trying to flag a possibly urgent issue affecting a real person.  If you know how to migrate to a better location, then please help.  Thank you.

Comment: @SebastianSimonSe just because it stemmed from a post on Travel doesn't mean it can't be discussed in a network-wide scope. If [discussing concerns for self-harm](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243700/whats-the-official-se-response-to-serious-mentions-of-suicide-or-self-harm) is valid, why wouldn't this be? And indeed, the way it's phrased, I only took the Travel post as a supporting example, nothing more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks for asking. This is a complicated situation: yes, the activity being discussed is dangerous, but it is also sometimes a necessity - [there are numerous other questions about traveling as a minor](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/minors), and more that aren't tagged as such. Indeed, [I had to ask a question about this myself on behalf of someone else](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/26787/how-can-i-have-will-call-greyhound-tickets-picked-up-without-a-photo-id).

The best thing to do here is to *assume good faith* and try to provide as much support and guidance as possible - you're off to a good start with your answer, but if you can dig up links to local organizations that might be able to offer direct assistance, that would be a much more useful addition than the cautions you currently have.

As always, downvote and/or flag any answers that provide dangerous advice - this is not the place to tolerate misinformation, as someone may end up hurt or worse as a result.