# On-topic (non-closed & non-locked) posts that you're not allowed to answer?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, deleted-answers

Is it true that there are types of (meta) posts that are on-topic, non-closed, and non-locked, that you're not allowed to answer?

I saw this [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) post on a per-site meta, and all the answers there *(excluding self-deleted answers)* have been deleted by a moderator with this comment:

> This post is a Public Service Announcement and doesn't take answers.

<sub>(Note: I am not talking about posting an answer when an answer (or more) already exists; just posting answers in general.)</sub>

Comment: Have you tried asking on that particular site meta about it? Different sites are allowed to be somewhat different.

Comment: @RobertLongson No, because I wanted the word of the big meta. An answer stating that only some sites might have this type of post because xyz is also valid.

Comment: Here on MSE you can answer anything (at your own risk) as far as I can tell. If you try to add additional answers to a FAQ post we'd delete them but that's about all really.

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399620/unnecessary-secondary-accounts-and-avoiding-moderator-action/399648#399648) on MSO is kind of a public service announcement but has answers that the moderators there have not deleted. So YMMV (Your Meta May Vary).

Comment: @RobertLongson Hmm, I've not heard of any restriction on adding answers to FAQ posts in general. There seem to be several such posts with multiple answers.

Comment: @cigien there are [plenty](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121350/ive-just-been-downvoted-how-should-i-react) [of examples](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account) but sure it's not universal.

Comment: @RobertLongson [Only one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq?tab=Unanswered) [ faq ] post on MSE (of the 156 posts) has no upvoted or accepted answer(s)...

Comment: When you say "Not allowed" you mean that the answer will just be deleted by a mod-privileged user, not that you would be mechanically not allowed to post an answer to them, right? (i.e. that you would be blocked from posting despite the question not being closed/locked/protected/etc.)

Comment: @Spevacus I mean that the answer will just be deleted by a mod-privileged user, which, to me, clearly indicates that the action "wasn't allowed" ;)

Comment: Well - it's an unusual situation, and without context, it's hard to judge the intention of the moderator.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well, I do believe we can lock and protect questions on meta in the usual way.

[In this case](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410831/11171084) - I guess that locks were not finely grained enough - mods wanted to allow comments but not answered, and assumed folks would read the tab excerpt for the [special PSA tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/psa)

The comments also indicate

> @41686d6564: there already is a psa tag on the post, and there is no 'answer' lock option. So far all we got is 1 mistaken comment (self-deleted), 1 misinformed answer post and 1 rant, and none would not have qualified as answers even if there was a discussion point here. Nothing we can't handle.

As such this is very much a site policy - akin to the official [policy lock here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349276/135565)

Mods are human exception handlers. Sometimes when the tools we have are insufficient, we figure out our own, off label solutions. As such - well this is clearly a problem the Stack Overflow mods needed people to know about and be able to refer to without actually opening up the floor to answers. That's what they feel works best and any review should be on per site meta

If other sites choose to adopt this, it might be worth considering a formal PSA lock in consultation with the company

Answer (score 5):

I've seen it rarely here on Meta SE but it's important to recognize that this sort of stigma around a post (at least here on Meta SE) is typically there for a good reason. The example I'd give is [this question regarding Stack Exchange's stance on self-harm and suicide](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355421/622284). The reasoning there being kinda clear: This is here to relay the moderation policy on that kind of situation, and nothing else.

That post has one answer from a staff member, and there are two deleted answers there, with the first chronologically-posted one having the following comment from a staff member:

> Hi, (username) - this is an official policy post so we keep it with the official policy only.

Which says to me that further answers to that post would meet the same fate. The second answer (posted by the same user as the other deleted answer) was deleted by a non-staff moderator (and also has helpful spam/abusive flags on it...) but I believe the stance around that post still stands.

While that post does have a policy lock on both the parent question and answer, and it's also protected, users could very well still post answers there. I'd still consider that "not allowed" as the answer would almost definitely be deleted though (and with good reason, in my opinion - there's no need for more to be there).

That post doesn't seem to be what you're *really* talking about, though. What you seem to be getting at is a situation where community moderators decided that an unlocked and open (not closed) question is there only to be an announcement and is not to be answered. I would say that it really depends on the context, and the context around [this Meta SO question you mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/410831/11171084) is fairly clear. That's a PSA (they even made [a tag for it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/psa)) and it's just there to relay a moderation policy. If the situation calls for it, moderators are entrusted with the tools to maintain this level of enforcement, even if they don't really have a lock type that fits it.

So yes, these kind of posts do exist, but they're only made and maintained in this way for good reasons.